# MySQL Query Interval date time

Tags: mysql

I have two table, 
first name named `time`

```
date_time    f1    f2
2019-03-02   3     7
2019-03-03   5     3
2019-03-04   2     5
2019-03-05   1     9
2019-03-06   6     2
2019-03-07   3     1
2019-03-08   2     4
2019-03-09   1     8
```

And I have table named `event`

```
date          event
2019-03-03    holiday
2019-03-07    parade
```

I want get data `date` until **next two days** from table `event` and then get the max value of data `f1` and `f2` so the result must be below

```
date              event      f1(max)      f2(max) 
2019-03-03       holiday      5             9
2019-03-07       parade       3             8
```

I just tried run my query

```
SELECT b.date_event,max(a.f1),max(a.f2) 
FROM time a  JOIN event b 
WHERE a.`date_time` >= b.`date_event` and 
a.`date_time` <=  date_add(b.`date_event`, interval 2 day)
```

But the result not match with what I expected

```
    date              event      f1(max)      f2(max) 
 2019-03-07           parade      6             9
```

You can see the result just get one date and the `f1` and `f2` max result is max value from table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could try using correlated subqueries to find the max values:

```
SELECT
    e.date,
    e.event,
    (SELECT MAX(f1) FROM time t
     WHERE t.date_time BETWEEN e.date AND DATE_ADD(e.date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)) AS f1_max,
    (SELECT MAX(f2) FROM time t
     WHERE t.date_time BETWEEN e.date AND DATE_ADD(e.date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)) AS f2_max
FROM event e
ORDER BY
    e.date;
```

Comment: Why you put `e.date` and `e.event`, cause when I run the query it'is failed because unknown column `date` and `event`

Comment: I suspect that you are not running my exact query.  Instead, you are running a modification.

Comment: sorry, i just realized I wrote wrong query. Now the result same with my expectation, thanks !